# cannot install openoffice

Tags: xubuntu, openoffice.org

first time user of xubuntu here! at my wits end trying to install openoffice. have uninstalled libreoffice so now i feel like a complete loser. the closest i came to was when i did 
    coelacanth@coelacanth:~/Downloads/en-US/DEBS$ sudo dpkg -i  *.deb

it seemed to be unpacking previously deselcted package and in the end
    Setting up openoffice-calc (4.1.1-6) ...
Setting up openoffice-brand-calc (4.1.1-6) ...

then nothing seems to be happening, and a cursory search shows i dont have openoffice on my xubuntu yet. what did i do wrong?
i had downloaded a tar gz file and extracted it and opened a terminal at the folder which had the deb files...

Comment: What is wrong with libreoffice ? If you did not get an error message OpenOffice should be installed. If you have a problem you may need to contact OpenOffice as it is 3rd party software. If you would like support here , please provide an error message or a better description of your problem.

Comment: didnt like it i guess. esp the spreadsheet. and looked very primitive reminiscent of notepad. but problem solved! so thanks anyway

Comment: What's wrong with LibreOffice is that much of a *.docx document blinks for no apparent reason. This is a known issue, even with the latest v.5 release. I simply can't deal with the blinking text all over my document, have found no way to fix it (font effects => blinking is NOT set), and OO doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running OpenOffice fine on my xubuntu 14.04.
Three things to keep in mind:

1. Make sure you really removed any LibreOffice package prior installing OpenOffice (for example using:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
   ```
2. Install the OpenOffice `.deb` files; like you did
3. don't forget about the DESKTOP integration, so under en-US/DEBS

   ```
   cd desktop-integration
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

From what you are writing, you might have missed "3."

Comment: thanks a lot! yes, missed the third step. w00t w00t!